# Reload table after ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a dynamic table where user can add/remove row, fill all the details and then submit these details. 
Once user submit the details I store them in DB and then I want to remove all content of table and show the empty table again.

```
  $.ajax({
                url: 'SaveQAStatus',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(jsonString),
                contentType: 'text/html',

                success: function (data) {
                    // I want to clear all the rows and just show original table which has onel 1 empty row
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                     console.log("Something really bad happened " + textStatus);
                     console.log(errorThrown);
                     console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
                },
            });
```

Any help

Comment: $("table#id").html(''), $("table#id").children().remove() ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all the table rows except first and make `td` of first row empty like below :

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'SaveQAStatus',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(jsonString),
                contentType: 'text/html',

                success: function (data) {
                    // I want to clear all the rows and just show original table which has onel 1 empty row
                 // remove all rows except first  
                 $('#tableId tr:not(:first)').remove();
                 //make all td empty for first row
                 $('#tableId tr:first td').each(function(){
                      $(this).html('');
                 });
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                     console.log("Something really bad happened " + textStatus);
                     console.log(errorThrown);
                     console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
                },
            });
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted but this gave me the direction of what I wanted to do. Thanks @Bhushan

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$("#tableid tbody tr").remove();
$("#tableid tr").remove();
$("#tableid tbody").html("");
```

depending if you're using a tbody or not